# How would I count these records using Linq to NHibernate (3.1)

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have an entity defined like so:

```
public class TestEntity : EntityBase
{
    public string Source {get;set;}
    public bool Suppressed {get;set;}

    /* other stuff */
}
```

I want to show an HTML table that looks like:

```
Source       Suppressed      Not Suppressed
-------------------------------------------------
Source1      30              1225
Soure        7               573
```

My first attempt to query this was:

```
from e in _session.Query<TestEntity>()
group e by e.Source into g1
select new 
{
    Source = g1.Key,
    Suppressed = g1.Sum(x=>x.Suppressed ? 1 : 0),
    NotSuppressed = g1.Sum(x=>x.Suppressed ? 0 : 1),
}
```

But of course, Linq choked on the ternary expression when converting it to SQL. Any alternative ways to do this?

Edit: I tried Dmitry's suggestion, and it returns the same counts for both. The SQL generated by his suggestion is:

```
select
    customer0_.SourceA as col_0_0_,
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_1_0_,
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_2_0_ 
from
    dbo.Customers customer0_ 
group by
    customer0_.SourceA
```

Which obviously isn't what I want...

Answer (score 3):

What about doing something like `g1.Count(x => x.Suppressed == true)`?

Comment: Tried that just now. Because the object is returned either way, the count is the same for both suppressed and not suppressed. In SQL, I get around this by doing the sum(case...end) statement I was trying to mimick originally.

Comment: It is probably an NHibernate bug if the predicate condition is ignored.